# Problem with Abstract class, Interface, Container and methods

Tags: c#, interface, ioc-container, abstract-class

I've the following scenario

I've an Interface

```
public interface ImyInterface
{
    void myInterfaceMethod(string param);
}
```

I've an Abstract Class

```
public abstract class myAbstractClass
{
    public myAbstractClass()
    {
       //something valid for each inherited class
    }

    public void myAbstractMethod<T>(T param)
    {
      //something with T param
    }
}
```

I've a class that inherits from myAbstractClass and implements ImyInterface

```
public class myClass : myAbstractClass, ImyInterface
{
    public myClass():base()
    {}

    public void ThisMethodWillNeverCall()
    {
       // nothing to do
    }                    
}
```

And, finally, I've a class where I'll create a ImyInterface object. At this point I would call myAbstractMethod, but...

```
public class myFinalClass
{
    public void myFinalMethod()
    {
       ImyInterface myObj = _myContainer<ImyInterface>();

       myObj.???

    }
}
```

Obviously there isn't this method because it isn't declared into the interface.
My solution is the following

```
public interface ImyInterface
{
   void myInterfaceMethod(string param);
   void myFakeMethod<T>(T param);
}

public class myClass : myAbstractClass, ImyInterface
{
   public myClass():base()
   {}

   public void ThisMethodWillNeverCall()
   {
      // nothing to do
   }

   //--- a fake method
   public void myFakeMethod<T>(T param)
   {
         base.myAbstractMethod<T>(param);
   }                    
 }
```

Is there any other solution better than mine?

Thank you!

Comment: why do you think this is a problem?  if the method is required by code that uses the interface it should be part of the interface.

Comment: If you're working with interfaces, then obviously the methods need to be declared on them.

Comment: Ditch the interface, use the abstract class.

Comment: Just a note but `void myAbstractMethod()` is not abstract. This distracts and confuses the reader. Maybe the writer too.

Comment: @Jason: it's not a real problem, but maybe is there solution better than mine

Comment: myFakeMethod will still not be available when you create an instance like this ImyInterface myObj = _myContainer<ImyInterface>(); How does this solve your problem ?

Comment: @Pkay: Sorry, I've write the wrong method name into the Interface, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your naming convention is a mess. Read up on the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) that Microsoft have made.

It's also hard to tell what you are trying to achieve based on your example.

**Back to your question:**

You should only access an interface to work with that interface. Don't try to make any magic stuff with classes/interfaces to get them working together. That usually means that the class shouldn't try to implement the interface.

It's better that you create a new interface which have the features that you want and let your class implement both.

Comment: It's an example, I've tried to write as simple as possible. Thank you, I'll create a new interface as you suggest.